# How to order by total_sales then rand in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm actually working on an e-commerce development and I need help. I'm trying to sort the product by total_sales. The problem is, some products exists in different variations (The product A, The product B... etc) and I don't want them to be sticked together. When my products have the same number of sales (ex: 0), all the 0 sales products are ordered by name, and I want them to be ordered randomly.

To make it simple, I want to order the products by total_sales and when the total_sales are the same, order them randomly.

I've tried things like

```
$args['meta_key'] = 'total_sales'
$args['orderby'] = 'rand,meta_value_num';
$args['order'] = 'DESC';
```

*for this line I've tried :

```
rand,meta_value_num ; meta_value_num,rand ; rand meta_value_num ; meta_value_num rand
```

but none of these worked.

Could you please help me ?

Comment: you can use this. :---

$query = new WP_Query( //arguments );
shuffle( $query->posts );  Use shuffle(); ..
or only use this :--- 'orderby' => 'rand',

Comment: If I do that, I'll lose the popularity sorting, won't I ?